# How to use a slice of QSqlQueryModel?

Tags: python, c++, sql, qt

I have a `QSqlQueryModel` containing the result of a query than can have several 10,000 rows.

I than have two use cases for this model:

1. One use case in which I need the full model to compute some statistics on the rows;
2. One use case where I want to display an **overview** of the content.

My problem is with the second case, what would be a proper way to "slice" the QSqlQueryModel to display only the N first records ?

I thought of several solutions but that are either not fully suitable or couldn't manage to make them work:

- Add a `LIMIT` in the query: not suitable because of case 1. I could imagine having 2 models (one with limit and one without) but

  - not really nice
  - the query comes from user input, so he/she can have inserted a LIMIT already, can't have two
- Pagination for the display but couldn't understand how to do it in practice (currently, the whole model is displayed with a `QTableView`) Is there a better choice?

My code right now is basically:

```
QString q = query_edit->toPlainText();
QSqlQuery query (q);
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
model->setQuery(query);
QTableView *result_view = new QTableView;
result_view->setModel(model);
```

Comment: If you are using ID numbers for records you could use `QSortFilterProxyModel` and set filter to your ID column.

Answer (score 1):

I would really encourage you to use two models. If you want to change stuff afterwards you will enjoy the freedom.

I you still want a single model you could do the following things:

1. Subclass QSqlQueryModel
2. Reimplement the `int rowCount(...)` const method to suit your needs. If you need some fancy overview stuff -> reimplement the `QVariant data(...) const` and i`nt columnCount(...) const` methods as well.
3. Implement some kind of raw output function to get all data for your statistical analysis.